# How to create Webdriver for custom WebKit Browser

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, webkit

My company works with POS and we're using a custom browser based on Chrome (webkit) with a few (minor) changes in its behavior.

We're creating automated tests with Selenium using Chrome, but now it's time to move to the custom browser instead.
How to proceed? I see many questions related to custom capabilities, but none related to custom browsers.

Comment: Are you using QtWebkit?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify details on programing language, what exception you got from setting Chrome binary to your custom browser, etc... So I'll make some assumptions.

First of all, from my experience it's achievable, but I can't remember the exact details, except that we had some versioning issue that we needed to comply with on our custom browser.

However, my suggestion to you is to clone [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) and create a `new ChromeDriver()` with your cloned project in debug mode, and see where it fails, then look for the specific solution, and continue from there.